# How to get the latest updated item from LiveData?

Tags: android-studio, android-livedata, android-database

Everytime i add new item to database using Livedata, it is retriving all data from database. But i want only the latest updated item to display on the screen when i click save button

Here is the Code

**MAIN ACTIVITY**

```
 viewModel.retrieveItem(idd).observe(this , Observer{
                    selectedItem = it
                        if(selectedItem != null){
                            entry = selectedItem as Entry
                            bind(entry)
                        }else{
                            blank()
                        }


   

private fun bind(entry: Entry){
       editText.setText(entry.diaryEntry,TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)
    }
```

**VIEW MODEL**

```
  fun  retrieveItem(id: Int): LiveData<Entry> {
        return diaryDao.getItem(id)
    }
```

**DAO**

```
  @Query("SELECT * from diary WHERE id = :id")
     fun  getItem(id: Int): LiveData<Entry>
```

*Any help would be Appreciated*